# Does the Flash sweat when running?

Tags: dc, the-flash

We know that the flash [doesn't tire out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82073/40833), but he's still running.  When other people run they tend to sweat, does the Flash do this? Has the comics ever show him sweating after any sort of run?

Comment: Does Flash ever get knocked out within seconds because of dehydration?

Comment: Flash is still human so I would assume he still sweats, just as he has to eat extra to counter the energy he burns running... I would think that the lack of sweat visible would be due to the speeds he is running; given it dries rapidly... just a thought. I haven't found anything online yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of the Flash are you talking about?

In the comics from the 70s, I've only seen him sweat when it is really hot out (and he's not running), nervous, or when he's sick with a fever.

I seem to recall him sweating from over exertion but in the race with Superman, (when he is presumably going all out) he is not shown sweating.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific than "the comics form the 70s". Any chance you could provide an example issue where he sweats?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably too late to answer the question now, but I'd like to add a few shreds of evidence to the plate (from the TV series-The Flash and not the comics)

- S04-E15 ***"Enter Flashtime"***: One can see Barry sweating (heavily, I must say, and it was mainly because of heat emitted due to detonation of a nuke) when he comes to Iris, scared and 'tired', and thinking, that he can not save the city this time.
- S04-E10 ***"The Trials of The Flash"***: One can clearly notice Barry sweating while he is trying to contain the radiation being emitted by the fallout (Neil Borman).

I don't remember watching Flash sweating (or getting that very tired, in fact) in any of the previous seasons.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! It's fine to answer questions late as long as you're contributing something new. In the "Enter Flashtime" example, is he sweating because he was running, or is he sweating because he is nervous? If it's the latter, then it doesn't count.

Comment: He was sweating mainly because of the heat being emitted due to the detonation of the nuclear bomb.

Comment: Then it wasn't his running that made him sweat, therefore it doesn't count, unfortunately.

Comment: @F1Krazy, right. But that heat also exhausted him, and of course one sweats when one is exhausted and not just because one is running. Isn't it valid then?