# Can the Flash get HIV (or any STD)

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash

So this may sound like a weird question because it is. But I want to know if it would be possible for the Flash (Barry Allen or Wally West) could get an STD and if he does get an STD (specifically HIV) would he be able to burn it off by making his immune system run at super speed or something, I know there are different iterations and I don't really want to site a specific one, but for this question let's assume that the Flash's bodily functions are always running faster then normal. Kind of like how in some shows he needs to constantly eat since he burns through food quickly. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Or indeed, why not any mundane disease?

Comment: Now that's the definition of "running away from your problems"!

Comment: Poorly answered here (no citations): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47627/is-the-flashs-physiology-faster-than-normal-humans